# How to check if ancestor is last element of that type in his ancestor

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a following XML:

```
<TABLE>
  <ROW>
    <ENTRY/>
    <ENTRY/>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <ENTRY>xxx</ENTRY>
    <ENTRY>yyy</ENTRY>
  </ROW>
  <Z>
    <ROW>
      <ENTRY/>
      <ENTRY/>
    </ROW>
  </Z>
  <ROW>
    <ENTRY/>
    <ENTRY/>
  </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

The table structure can change, so I could have last row wrapped in Z element, or there could be no Z element at all.

My goal is to remove the bottom border in entries of the last row in table.
(TABLE maps to HTML table, ROW to HTML tr, ENTRY to HTML td)

so I try to use xslt template:

```
<xsl:template match="ENTRY">
  <td>
    <xsl:if test="(ancestor::ROW[1] = ancestor::TABLE[1]/descendant::ROW[last()])">
      <!-- remove the bottom border of td -->
    </xsl:if>  
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

But it removes the border from almost all the cells in table (the border is not removed from cells that have text content). So i guess the mechanism checks if the nodes have the same value (name, text content, children and so on) - not references.
I've tried to use some external function in java, but I always get a new reference of node (even for the same nodes) so I can't compare it.

So my question is - how to compare the references of nodes...
or do the job in any other way.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is to remove the bottom border in entries of the last row in
>   table. (TABLE maps to HTML table, ROW to HTML tr, ENTRY to HTML td)

**It seems that you want**:

```
<xsl:if test=
  "generate-id(ancestor::ROW[1]) 
  = 
   generate-id(ancestor::TABLE[1]/descendant::ROW[last()])">

  <!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:if>
```

**I recommend that you add a new template and use pattern matching** (instead of explicit conditional) to capture this case:

```
<xsl:template match=
"ENTRY[generate-id(ancestor::ROW[1]) 
      = 
       generate-id(ancestor::TABLE[1]/descendant::ROW[last()])
      ]">

      <!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Your more general question:

> So my question is - how to compare the references of nodes

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) use the [`is`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-is-same-node) operator**:

```
$n1 is $n2
```

tests the two nodes `$n1` and `$n2` for node identity (not value equality).

**In XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0):**

```
count($n1|$n2) = 1
```

**Another way in XSLT 1.0** is to use the standard XSLT 1.0 (not available in XPath 1.0) function **[`generate-id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-generate-id)**, as done in the above solution:

```
generate-id($n1) = generate-id($n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test `(ancestor::ROW[1] = ancestor::TABELA[1]/descendant::ROW[last()])` matches the first two and the last two `ENTRY` elements in your sample. Presumably because when rendered as strings the first `ROW` matches the last `ROW`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

I was able to select the last two entries using:

```
//ENTRY[count(ancestor::ROW[1]/preceding::ROW) = count(ancestor::TABLE[1]/descendant::ROW) - 1]
```

So I guess that the following would work as your test:

```
(count(ancestor::ROW[1]/preceding::ROW) = count(ancestor::TABLE[1]/descendant::ROW) - 1)
```

---

**Update** *Courtesy of feedback from Dimitre Novatchev and jasso*

This solution is not ideal as:

1. These counts are inefficient, counting more things than necessary.
2. `preceding::` axis may match more than just the descendants of the `TABLE` element when part of a larger document.

Comment: MattH: Such `count()` operations are not generally efficient and should be avoided, if possible.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Thanks for the feedback. I'll leave this inefficient solution here for comparison.

Comment: Just a general caution about using a `preceding` or `following` axis: The problem with them is that they break out of the expected scope and thus fail if there are repeated similar structures in the document. In this case that XPath fails if the real use case is more complex than the given sample code and there is more than one `<TABLE>` containing a `<ROW>`. With a single `<TABLE>` this works too.

Comment: @jasso: Excellent point. I'll update with this caution/caveat/limitation when I next get to a keyboard. I think there's value in keeping this suggested answer as a warning to others